# Batch script for copying files with folder

Tags: batch-file, cmd, copy, xcopy, robocopy

I have list of files path in `rarme.txt` file.
such as:

- D:\Test\Bin\test.dll
- D:\Test\Bin\test.exe
- D:\Test\Image\House\Door.bmp
- D:\Beta\AppHouse.dll

Now how to copy the files with only one or two level up folder

for ex: In case of

> D:\Test\Bin\test.dll

How to copy `test.dll` file within `Bin` folder?

and in case of

> D:\Test\Image\House\Door.bmp

how to copy `door.bmp` within `Image\House Folder`?

This bat script copies the file to location `D:\ForPatch` and rars it

```
Rem Copying files to folder
pause
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (rarme.txt) do xcopy "%%i" "D:\ForPatch" /s
pause
cd D:\ForPatch
pause
rar a  -ep1 -r Patch.rar *.*
pause
```

Comment: What's wrong with using this list directly? `rar a  -ep1 -r D:\ForPatch\Patch.rar @rarme.txt`

Comment: @wOxxOm This script created rar file but how do i create the sub folder inside rar ?

Comment: rar will store the paths of files just fine. At least this is how I understand the initial question...

Comment: I am afraid you didn't get the question however your suggestion helped to create rar without copying files to location and then rar all files in that location.Now my problem is how do i create the rar with only one level or two level folder hirerarchy

Answer (score 0):

Hoping I understand your aim:

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions
Rem Copying files to folder
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (rarme.txt) do (
  for /f "tokens=1,* delims=/\" %%J in ("%%~pi") do (
    echo if not exist "D:\ForPatch\%%~K" mkdir "D:\ForPatch\%%~K" 2>NUL
    echo copy /B "%%~i" "D:\ForPatch\%%~K%%~nxi"   
  )
)
```

Note that operational `mkdir` and `copy /B` commands are merely `echo`ed for debugging purposes. Remove `echo` no sooner than debugged.
**Output** using your data:

```
==>D:\bat\SO\31588128.bat
if not exist "D:\ForPatch\Bin\" mkdir "D:\ForPatch\Bin\"
copy /B "D:\Test\Bin\test.dll" "D:\ForPatch\Bin\test.dll"
if not exist "D:\ForPatch\Bin\" mkdir "D:\ForPatch\Bin\"
copy /B "D:\Test\Bin\test.exe" "D:\ForPatch\Bin\test.exe"
if not exist "D:\ForPatch\Image\House\" mkdir "D:\ForPatch\Image\House\"
copy /B "D:\Test\Image\House\Door.bmp" "D:\ForPatch\Image\House\Door.bmp"
if not exist "D:\ForPatch\" mkdir "D:\ForPatch\"
copy /B "D:\Beta\AppHouse.dll" "D:\ForPatch\AppHouse.dll"
```

Then next *operational* variant of the script should work supposing `rar` command is right (not tested as I do not have `rar` installed).

```
@ECHO OFF >NUL
SETLOCAL enableextensions
Rem Copying files to folder
for /f "tokens=*" %%i in (rarme.txt) do (
  for /f "tokens=1,* delims=/\" %%J in ("%%~pi") do (
    if not exist "D:\ForPatch\%%~K" mkdir "D:\ForPatch\%%~K" 2>NUL
    copy /B "%%~i" "D:\ForPatch\%%~K%%~nxi"   
  )
)
pushd D:\ForPatch
pause
rar a  -ep1 -r Patch.rar *.*
pause
popd
```

Comment: Thanks for you suggestion.But the files are not being copied.Therefore at time of creating rar Warning:no files found is shown.

Comment: @SangitGurung `if not exist` test adjusted. HTH.